# Display (OBJECT) Inside Array, Array Inside Object in Angular

Tags: arrays, angular, object

I'm confused on how would i display the material.name and project.name on the html. Here's the picture and codes below.

[image]

> ts

```
getAllMat() {
    this.subscription = this.matService.getAll()
      .subscribe(
        (data:any) => {
          this.mats = data.materialProjects;
          console.log(data);
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
  }
```

> html

```
    <tr *ngFor="let mat of mats">
                      <td>{{ mat.name }}</td>
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be  **`mat.material.name`** since material is an object,

```
 <tr *ngFor="let mat of mats">
   <td>{{ mat.material.name }}</td>
 </tr>
```